# Updating Active Directory user properties in Active Directory using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, adsi

In a Windows Server 2003 R2 environment, using Powershell v2.0, how would one duplicate the functionality of [Set-QADUser](http://wiki.powergui.org/index.php/Set-QADUser) to update user properties in Active Directory, like their phone number and title?

The trick here being, I would like to do this without depending on Set-QADUser and I do not have the option to use the Server 2008's commandlets, yet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Piecing things together from around the internet, I came up with this...

```
function Get-ADUser( [string]$samid=$env:username){
     $searcher=New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
     $searcher.Filter="(&(objectcategory=person)(objectclass=user)(sAMAccountname=$samid))"
     $user=$searcher.FindOne()
      if ($user -ne $null ){
          $user.getdirectoryentry()
     }
}

$user = Get-ADUser 'UserName'

# Output all properties
$user.psbase.properties

# Change some properties
$user.title = 'New Title'
$user.telephoneNumber = '5555551212'
$user.SetInfo()

# Output the results
$user.title
$user.telephoneNumber
```

More Information

- [Using PowerShell to work with ADSI to manage an Active Directory environment](http://psobject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ADSI%20and%20AD&ProjectName=psobject)
- [SelfADSI : The ADSI Scripting Tutorial / The LDAP Scripting Tutorial](http://www.selfadsi.org)
- [IADsUser Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746540%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: There is a lot you can do with ADSI & PowerShell, and a couple of other ways of doing things. For example if you need to set a password you can use:

$user.psbase.Invoke("SetPassword","PasswordGoesHere")
$user.psbase.CommitChanges()

Useful if you want to script creation of new user accounts.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the [ADSI objects](http://207.46.16.252/en-us/magazine/2007.06.powershell.aspx) in PowerShell. The syntax is going to look similar to vbscript because you are using the same component.